# rails3 - uninitialized constant in factory definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

`factory_girl` is not recognizing a model name that I've defined, and which I need to reference because I need a subclass.  This worked in rails 2 but I'm migrating to rails 3.

Factory definition:

```
Factory.define :interest, :class => Term::Interest do |f|
  f.name {"#{Factory.next(:lipsum_word)}ing"}
end
```

Definition of `Term` and `Term::Interest`

```
class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  class Interest < Term
  end

  class Award < Term
  end  
end
```

Error and stack trace:

```
$ rake db:data:load --trace
(in /Users/glurban/code/recruitd)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Term
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rspec-core-2.4.0/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing'
/Users/glurban/code/recruitd/test/factories/factories.rb:316:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/glurban/code/recruitd/lib/tasks/use_factories.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `block in load_tasks'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `each'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `load_tasks'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:141:in `load_tasks'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/glurban/code/recruitd/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `block in run'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/glurban/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

I tried adding `require_dependency 'term'` to the top of `factories.rb` but then I get

```
Glens-MacBook-Pro:test glurban$ rake db:data:load
(in /Users/glurban/code/recruitd)
rake aborted!
No such file to load -- term
```

What to do?

Edit: in response to the comment, yes, it happens only on rake, not in the console:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.0)
ruby-1.9.2-rc2 > Factory(:term)
 => #<Term id: 3, type: nil, name: "Proud to be a Recruitd user", location: nil, category_id: nil, description: nil, url: nil, created_at: "2011-01-06 21:30:14", updated_at: "2011-01-06 21:30:14"> 
ruby-1.9.2-rc2 > Factory(:interest)
 => #<Term::Interest id: 4, type: "Term::Interest", name: "siting", location: nil, category_id: nil, description: nil, url: nil, created_at: "2011-01-06 21:30:18", updated_at: "2011-01-06 21:30:18">
```

Custom rake task definition:

```
require 'factory_girl'
require File.expand_path("test/factories/factories.rb")

namespace :db do
  namespace :data do 

    desc "Load sample data"
    task :load => :environment do |t|
      create_students
      ...
      create_student_files_and_feeds
      puts "Completed loading sample data."
    end
  end
end

def create_interests
  data_fetch("interests").each do |input|
    Factory(:interest, :name => input.strip)
  end
  puts "Created interests"
end
```

Comment: does that error message only happen on that rake call and not on, say, rails console?

Comment: Is `data:load` a custom Rake task? If so, are you including the environment?

Comment: It may have to do with the way you have defined Term, Interest and Award.  Is there a reason that Interest and Award are nested in Term and are Terms themselves?

Comment: @pjammer: yeah, not in console.  edited the question to show it working in the console.

Comment: @zetetic: yep, custom rake task.  so you're saying... `rake db:data:load RAILS_ENV=development`?  Doesn't that happen automatically?

Comment: @Pan: yes, Interest and Award are kinds of Terms.  I guess I can un-nest them.

Comment: @unsorted: I meant your task needs to have (e.g.) `task :load => :environment do` to make the Rails environment available to Rake.

Comment: why'd you make a custom rake task?  I'd be interested in seeing that too. and the reason why lol.

Comment: @unsorted, you may also run into other problems with using straight factory_girl, there is a factory_girl_rails that is the supported library for rails 3, last I checked.

Comment: @pjammer added the custom rake task to the question.  It's basically to load sample data because I don't like fixtures.  @zetetic: yes, it's there.  @Jed: yeah, I'm using `factory_girl_rails` (actually I think both are loaded in the Gemfile).

Comment: you do know now though that you don't need that rake file for the purpose of loading though, eh?  Write your factories. Call them in your tests where you should be using fixtures and boom, it's all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking over the `factory_girl` documentation again, I realized that you can specify a class using either a string or a class constant.  So I tried using a string and it worked:

```
Factory.define :interest, :class => "Term::Interest" do |f|
  f.name {"#{Factory.next(:lipsum_word)}ing"}
end
```

Also, a comment about the nested classes.  I initially did that to keep the classes a little more organized, but given the complexity it's created (especially for routing), I'm just going to move each subclass to its own model file.  (If I were to un-nest them without putting them in separate files, rails seems to fail to find the subclasses sometimes--namely if the parent class hadn't been referenced (forcing the load of that file) before.